Unable to create file in specified directory because of security scope resource errors in iOS app
Goal: A user selects a folder in Files app where they would create files in that folder. This is an iOS app. This folder path is saved in the iOS app, using this app user would create file programmatically and save it in the app.
Issue: For some reason based on the below implementation, I can create file only onetime in that folder and any subsequent file creation leads to "Failed to access security scoped resource". To go around this, I need to select the folder again and then send it. THis is not the experience a user should face. A user should select the folder path only once and it is saved in iOS app, user should care about more about creating files in that folder.
Below is the code
class FolderManager: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    
    // Singleton instance for shared access
    static let shared = FolderManager()
    
    private override init() {}
    
    // Function to present the document picker for selecting a folder
    func selectFolder(from viewController: UIViewController) {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType.folder], asCopy: false)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        viewController.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // Delegate method called when a folder is selected
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let selectedFolderURL = urls.first else { return }
        saveFolderURL(selectedFolderURL)
    }
    
    // Function to save the folder URL as bookmark data
    func saveFolderURL(_ url: URL) {
        do {
            let bookmarkData = try url.bookmarkData(options: .minimalBookmark, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmarkData, forKey: "selectedFolderURL")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving folder URL: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func retrieveFolderURL() -> URL? {
            guard let bookmarkData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "selectedFolderURL") else { return nil }
            var isStale = false
            let folderURL = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: [], bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
            if isStale {
                print("Bookmark data is stale")
                // Handle stale bookmark data
                do {
                    let newBookmarkData = try folderURL?.bookmarkData(options: .minimalBookmark, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(newBookmarkData, forKey: "selectedFolderURL")
                } catch {
                    print("Error updating stale bookmark data: \(error)")
                }
            }
            return folderURL
        }
    
    // Function to create and save a file in the selected folder
    func createFileInFolder(fileName: String, fileContents: String) {
        guard let folderURL = retrieveFolderURL() else {
            print("Failed to retrieve folder URL")
            return
        }
        
        if !folderURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            print("Failed to access security scoped resource")
            return
        }
        defer {
            folderURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            print("stoppedAccessingSecurityScopedResource")
        }
        
        let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
        do {
            try fileContents.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            print("File created successfully at \(fileURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Error creating file: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

I already reviewed some stackoverflow snippets based on that the code is already modified as per startAccessingSecurityScopedResource, stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource.
Any help is highly appreciated.

I cannot reproduce. Please show a [mcve].

I am making a video. Are you sure you're not seeing the error after you sent the second time. @Sweeper

To address the issue of "Failed to access security scoped resource" when creating files in a previously selected folder in your iOS app, you need to manage security-scoped URLs properly. When a user selects a folder, you should bookmark the URL to retain access between app launches.
Step 1: Ask for Folder Permission and Save Bookmark
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var folderURL: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Select Folder") {
                selectFolder()
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button("Create File") {
                createFile()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    private func selectFolder() {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType.folder])
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        if let topController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController {
            topController.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    private func createFile() {
        guard let folderURL = folderURL else { return }
        do {
            let bookmarkData = try Data(contentsOf: folderURL)
            var isStale = false
            let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
            if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
                let fileURL = url.appendingPathComponent("newfile.txt")
                try "Hello, World!".write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                print("File created successfully")
            } else {
                print("Failed to access security scoped resource")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error creating file: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let url = urls.first else { return }
        do {
            let bookmarkData = try url.bookmarkData(options: .minimalBookmark, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmarkData, forKey: "selectedFolderBookmark")
            folderURL = url
        } catch {
            print("Error saving bookmark: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

Step 2: Retrieve and Use the Bookmark
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var folderURL: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Create File") {
                createFile()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            retrieveFolderURL()
        }
    }
    
    private func retrieveFolderURL() {
        guard let bookmarkData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "selectedFolderBookmark") else { return }
        do {
            var isStale = false
            let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
            folderURL = url
        } catch {
            print("Error retrieving bookmark: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func createFile() {
        guard let folderURL = folderURL else { return }
        if folderURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            defer { folderURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
            let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent("newfile.txt")
            do {
                try "Hello, World!".write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                print("File created successfully")
            } catch {
                print("Error creating file: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to access security scoped resource")
        }
    }
}


regarding "you should bookmark the URL" do you mean I should select the path from Files app between the launches?

@user4150758, please see the updated answer.
